# Finding Convergence for Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would appreciated any pointers or tips on how to find the convergence for

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 10\cdot(0.99)^{n}
$$

I know that this series converges to 1000, but I need some guidance on how this can be demonstrated.

Comment: What is the sum of a geometric series?

Comment: This is a geometric series, of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n$. These are some of the most well-understood infinite series. Have you seen anything about them before?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! That helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}\:\left(10\cdot \left(0.99\right)^n\right)$$
$$ $$
$$\mathrm{Apply\:the\:constant\:multiplication\:rule}:\quad \sum c\cdot a_n=c\cdot \sum a_n$$
$$=10\cdot \sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:}0.99^n$$
$$ $$
$$\mathrm{Apply\:Series\:Geometric\:Test}:$$
$$\mathrm{If\:the\:series\:is\:of\:the\:form\:}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }r^n$$
$$\mathrm{If\:}|r|<1\mathrm{,\:then\:the\:geometric\:series\:converges\:to\:}\frac{1}{1-r}$$
$$\mathrm{If\:}|r|\ge \:1\mathrm{,\:then\:the\:geometric\:series\:diverges}$$
$$r=0.99,\:|r|=0.99<1,\:\mathrm{by\:the\:geometric\:test\:criteria}$$
$$ $$
$$=10\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(0.99\right)}$$
$$=1000$$